# Fade effect with climb text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement fade effect with climb text on my web page. 
Example: http://www.believein.co.uk/ 
In this example on the main page we see when we hover mouse over image then image fade and text climb from the top. All what I imagine is that:

```
<div class="row pageTitle2">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 marPadReset">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/4.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".pageTitle2 img").fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    $(".pageTitle2 img").hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.6); 
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    });
```

Does anybody help?

Comment: Where is the text that you want to show on hover ? Also you don't need jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions for this, on hover you need to affect the opacity of the overlay background and the margin of the overlay text.

For example:

```
div#overlay_container:hover div#background {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

The above on hover of the overlay will change the opacity to `0.6` in an "eased" fashion.

```
div#overlay_container:hover div#text {
    transition: margin-top 2s ease-in-out, opacity 2s ease-in-out;

    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The above on hover of the overlay will change the `opacity` to `1` and the `margin-top` to `0`.

You can see the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NpR2Z/).

You may need to fall back to a Javascript based solution if you wish to cater for outdated browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/FCpc8/1/

**CSS**

```
a { position: relative; display: inline-block }
a span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: black;
 color: #fff;
 opacity:0;
 transition:1s;
}

a:hover span {
 opacity:1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row pageTitle2">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4 marPadReset">
           <a href="#">
               <span>Some Text</span>
            <img src="~/Content/Images/4.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Explanation**

First of all, you need to wrap the image in `anchor` tag and include the text you want to show on hover in a `span` tag. By default, the `opacity` of text will be 0, that is `hidden`. On hover `(a:hover span) opacity` is set to 1 - `visible`. and background is black hence the image behind is not visible. `Transition property` of css will help it move the effect smoothly.

Comment: if you could explain your answer, although it is better.

Comment: Sure. First of all, you need to wrap the image in `anchor` tag and includ the text you want to show on hover in a `span` tag. By default, the `opacity` of text will be `0`, that is hidden. On hover (a:hover span) `opacity` is set to `1` visible. and background is black hence the image behind is not visible. `Transition property` of css will help it move the effect smoothly

Comment: you have to explain you answer in your post otherwise no one gets what you have answered here. As OP has used jQuery/javascript for getting his/her result and you have not mentioned that in your answer here. so do that in your post then your answer will be worth noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery with some `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` effects

```
$(function(){
    $(".bg").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".text").fadeIn(500);
    });

    $(".bg").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".text").slideUp(500);
    });

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/hET96/)